# When adding ul element into Kendo Grid Column ul element always behind an other columns

Tags: css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I try to add ul element into kendo-grid-column. When I did ul element always look like as in the picture. z-index is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<kendo-grid-column>
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
    <span style="width: 100%; left: 0px;position: absolute; margin-top:52px;">
    <span style="width: 100%; position: relative;z-index:9999 !important;">
        <span>
        <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let itemData of dropData ; let i = index">
            {{itemData.Desc}}
            </li>
        </ul>
        </span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

My grid looks like the following:

[image]

Sorry for my English :)

Thank you...

Comment: z-index only work in positioned elements. You don´t really need to use !important in inline style, It will automatically override other styles

Comment: I removed !important but nothing change. Is the ul element not already positioned by the parent?

Comment: Could it be an overflow issue? https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/

Comment: Can you please share a working sample with a couple of grid rows? Would be easier to inspect the styles and get it right. The !important was doing nothing, this is why I suggest to remove it.

Comment: Yes it is an overflow problem. When I set 'overflow: inherit' style of dropdown parent td element problem is solved. Thank you Carlos Martins and GaloisGirl.